# How to force test failure - Java, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have this code for calling external service and I have to make a test for when we expect that failure to connecting external service will happen or/also for when data is not returned

This is code for calling `Data` service:

```
@Override
public Optional<DataResponse> getData(String dataId, Author author) {
    try{
        JsonNode node = restTemplate.exchange(
                "/data/{dataId}?brand={author}",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(buildRequest(dataId, author), headers()),
                JsonNode.class
        ).getBody();
        return dataResponse(node);
    }catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        String msg = String.format(
                "Error getting data data for dataId %s and author %s",
                dataId,
                author,
                e.getStatusCode(),
                e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        LOGGER.error(msg);
        throw new RuntimeException(msg);
    }
}
```

My questions regarding the code are:

1. I am catching the `HttpStatusCodeException`and then should I also use this line of code `throw new HttpStatusCodeException(msg, "No return data");`to display some custom message?
2. How my test for connection failure should look like. For good connection I made this test:

   public class HttpDataServiceTest {

   ```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
    private final HttpDataService httpDataService = new HttpDataService(restTemplate);

    @Test
    public void getData(){

        ObjectNode responseNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
        responseNode.put("dataId", "");
        responseNode.put("author", "");
        responseNode.put("authorDataId", "");
        responseNode.put("serverSideDataId", "");

        Mockito
            .when(restTemplate.exchange(
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq("/game/{gameId}?brand={brandName}"),
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                    ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                    ArgumentMatchers.<Class<JsonNode>>any()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(responseNode, HttpStatus.OK));

        httpDataService.getData("dataIdTest", author.Potter);


    }
   ```

   }

But for testing error handling and bad request what should I do?

**UPDATE**

```
ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response;

Mockito
            .when(response=restTemplate.exchange(
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq("/game/{gameId}?brand={brandName}"),
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                    ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                    ArgumentMatchers.<Class<JsonNode>>any()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(responseNode, HttpStatus.OK));

        httpDataService.getData("dataIdTest", author.Potter);

 assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), (HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

Comment: You can check whether Rest Test Template does what you need instead of mocking it via Mockito: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testresttemplate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `thenThrow` function from `Mockito`.

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
    ArgumentMatchers.eq("/game/{gameId}?brand={brandName}"),
    ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
    ArgumentMatchers.any(),
    ArgumentMatchers.<Class<JsonNode>>any()))
   .thenThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
```

Edit:

`thenThrows` method is similar to the `thenReturn` method that you have used. The difference here with `thenThrows` is it `throws` the exception that you have given.

You can also check [these link](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Okay can you explain more with words :) Or how can I make test in my question to fail? Like in way if this happens then test will fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use custom message you can create a global exception handler and handle all exceptions. https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler/
   This provides flexibility to handle the exception across all  your endpoints.
2. You can throw HttpClientErrorException which extends abstract class HttpStatusCodeException

```
Mockito
            .when(restTemplate.exchange(
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq("/game/{gameId}?brand={brandName}"),
                    ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                    ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                    ArgumentMatchers.<Class<JsonNode>>any()))
            .thenThrow(HttpClientErrorException.class);
    
assertThrows(HttpStatusCodeException.class,()->{
            httpDataService.getData("dataIdTest", author.Potter);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You could force a 403 bad request by violating the api of the other api.